# How to see the actual Mongo calls being made from Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to log the actual calls to MongoDB being made from my MongooseJS connection.

1) How can I access this information from within my NodeJS app? I assume the Mongoose library must make something available? I would want to use winston to log this.

2) Bonus. How can I see the calls coming in from the MongoDB side itself?

Comment: Are you looking for the http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html. `mongoose.set('debug', true)`

Comment: And you can call a custom function instead of outputting to the console: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/666

Comment: Yes! Both of these comments are spot on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Node.JS/Mongoose, you can do it this way:

```
mongoose.set( "debug", true );
```

And, for the MongoDB, the best I can remember right now is that you can access `http://(server address):(mongod port + 1000)`.

For example:
If your mongod is running at port 27017 (default), then you can access this page with `http://localhost:28017`.

The far I can remember, this page doesn't actually show you the exactly queries being run, but it shows what collections are being queried, and how many documents are affected.

Also, you can see much more interesting data in this page.

Comment: Spot on. Also that trick with adding 1000 to the port number is great! That's awesome - thank you.